# Can I name each class that derives from an interface?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface `MuInterface` (abstract class). And I have 3 classes that derive from that interface:

```
class A : public MyInterface //...
class B : public MyInterface //...
class C : public MyInterface //...
```

I have a vector of interfaces: `std::vector< std::shared_ptr< MyInterface > > theVec;` that contains objects of type `A`, `B` and `C`. Is there a possibility to know in a for loop that iterates through that vector to display the type of the current object (if it is `A`, `B` or `C`)? I thought of something like a static string member, but how to "virtualize" it? Is it ok if I use a virtual function that displays the static const string:

```
virtual const std::string getType() { return classType; } // classType is static const std::string defined for each class
```

?

Comment: Yes it is, but the whole point of using an interface is to abstract the actual type away. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You might want to consider CRTP if you need some sort of type identification

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I need it just in debug mode to see that the order is good, but I have verified it and it is OK. I will put the display things in the classes A, B and C. This way is better, I think. Thanks

Comment: @sop For a quick debugging solution, `#include <typeinfo>` and then you can display `typeid(*(theVec[n])).name()` ([example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luchian pointed out the purpose of an interface is usually to hand out a "contract" which should be fulfilled regardless of the type: as long as you provide the interface's functionality you're all set.

Not sure why you need it but you can force a type identification by requesting to provide a `getType`-like function (*that is surely possible*)

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual const std::string identify() = 0;
};

class A : public MyInterface {
public:
    const std::string identify() {
        return std::string("A");
    }
};

// ... the same for B and C ...

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface>> theVec;
    theVec.push_back(std::make_shared<A>());
    theVec.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());
    theVec.push_back(std::make_shared<C>());

    std::cout << theVec[0]->identify();
    std::cout << theVec[1]->identify();
    std::cout << theVec[2]->identify();
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/vbc60B)</kbd>

Another more perverted solution could be to specialize your methods with a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern although I think it would be overkill in this case.

Comment: If it's just for debugging a quick `typeid` could work too, I suppose.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, although there might be some demangling inbetween.